# PySpark crashes when creating new column by applying function upon existing columns in large df

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I have the following dataframe created from a compressed 10gb .gz file in csv format:

```
+-------------------+----------+--------+----+
|           tweet_id|      date|    time|lang|
+-------------------+----------+--------+----+
|1212360731695427584|2020-01-01|13:11:37|  en|
|1212470713338286081|2020-01-01|20:28:39|  ru|
|1212537749485449216|2020-01-02|00:55:01|  ru|
+-------------------+----------+--------+----+
```

I am attempting to make a new column by transforming the date and time string colums into a unix timestamp:

```py
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession
from pyspark.sql.functions import udf
from pyspark.sql.types import IntegerType, StringType
from datetime import datetime, date
import time

spark = SparkSession.builder.appName("Tweets").getOrCreate()
df = spark.read.csv('tweets.gz', header=True, sep=r'\t')

def tounixtime(date_s, time_s):
    if None in (date_s, time_s):
        return -1
    
    ymd = tuple([int(x) for x in date_s.split("-")])
    t = [int(x) for x in time_s.split(":")]
    d = date(*ymd).timetuple()
    return int(time.mktime(d) + t[0] * 3600 + t[1] * 60 + t[2])
        
tounix = udf(tounixtime, IntegerType())

df.withColumn('timestamp', tounix(df.date, df.time)).show()
```

I get an exception that an error occurred in some stage of the process, and that python failed to reconnect. I'm not sure what's wrong here

Comment: any reason using UDF instead of spark's native `unix_timestamp` function?

Comment: I wasn't aware of it. It never came up in other StackOverflow functions regarding this conversion. Thank you, I will try it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without using any function, a simple cast can do the job as your data are pretty neat :

```py
from pyspark.sql import functions as F

df_2 = df.withColumn(
    "tmst", F.concat_ws(" ", F.col("date"), F.col("time")).cast("timestamp")
)  # or F.concat(F.col("date"), F.lit(" "), F.col("time"))

df_2.show()
+-------------------+----------+--------+----+-------------------+
|           tweet_id|      date|    time|lang|               tmst|
+-------------------+----------+--------+----+-------------------+
|1212360731695427584|2020-01-01|13:11:37|  en|2020-01-01 13:11:37|
|1212470713338286081|2020-01-01|20:28:39|  ru|2020-01-01 20:28:39|
|1212537749485449216|2020-01-02|00:55:01|  ru|2020-01-02 00:55:01|
+-------------------+----------+--------+----+-------------------+

df_2.printSchema()
root
 |-- tweet_id: long (nullable = true)
 |-- date: string (nullable = true)
 |-- time: string (nullable = true)
 |-- lang: string (nullable = true)
 |-- tmst: timestamp (nullable = true)
```